Unexpected Filter behavior of the attributes present on relations in AnzoGraph
I am developing an application where I want to fetch some relations present in the AnzoGraph. These relations have some attributes and I want to fetch data by applying filter the attribute present on relation. But while fetching data from AnzoGraph frontend, I encountered some weird behaviors.
For e.g. I am inserting below 2 vertices in AnzoGraph.
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>
INSERT DATA {
  GRAPH <http://anzograph.com/graphN> {
    ex:obj1 a ex:Object .
    ex:obj1 ex:Name "obj1"^^xsd:string .
    ex:obj1 ex:s_id "18"^^xsd:integer .
  }
}
 
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>
INSERT DATA {
  GRAPH <http://anzograph.com/graphN> {
    ex:obj2 a ex:Object .
    ex:obj2 ex:Name "obj2"^^xsd:string .
    ex:obj2 ex:s_id "19"^^xsd:integer .
  }
}

Now created a relation between these 2 vertices with below query.
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>
INSERT DATA {
  GRAPH <http://anzograph.com/graphN>
{
<<<ex:obj1> <edgeSample> <ex:obj2>>> ex:Name "edgeobj1"^^xsd:string .
<<<ex:obj1> <edgeSample> <ex:obj2>>> ex:Double "47.1234"^^xsd:double .
<<<ex:obj1> <edgeSample> <ex:obj2>>> ex:Int "123"^^xsd:int .
<<<ex:obj1> <edgeSample> <ex:obj2>>> ex:Name "41"^^xsd:float .
  }
}

Now when I am applying a filter on the relation attribute Double, I am observing below wired behavior.
Note: I am using OPTIONAL because in my case there might be chance, where double(or some of the attributes) attribute may not be present on some relations.
Case1: Filter on Double attribute
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>
SELECT ?start ?end (IRI(<edgeSample>) AS ?labels) ?attr1 ?attr2 ?attr3 ?attr4 
FROM <http://anzograph.com/graphN>
WHERE { 
?start <edgeSample> ?end . 
OPTIONAL{<< ?start <edgeSample> ?end >> ex:Name ?attr1 } . 
OPTIONAL{<< ?start <edgeSample> ?end >> ex:Double ?attr2 } . 
OPTIONAL{<< ?start <edgeSample> ?end >> ex:Int ?attr3 } . 
OPTIONAL{<< ?start <edgeSample> ?end >> ex:Name ?attr4 } . 
FILTER(?attr2 = "47.1234"^^xsd:double) 
}

Output : Error - m_type == row->a_field_type(m_colnum):Invalid system state type mismatch for var(?attr2) vartype(19): rowtype(4).
Because of above exception we tried case 2.
Case 2 : Using str() function in filter
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
 
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>
SELECT ?start ?end (IRI(<edgeSample>) AS ?labels) ?attr1 ?attr2 ?attr3 ?attr4 
FROM <http://anzograph.com/graphN>
 
WHERE { 
?start <edgeSample> ?end . 
OPTIONAL{<< ?start <edgeSample> ?end >> ex:Name ?attr1 } . 
OPTIONAL{<< ?start <edgeSample> ?end >> ex:Double ?attr2 } . 
OPTIONAL{<< ?start <edgeSample> ?end >> ex:Int ?attr3 } . 
OPTIONAL{<< ?start <edgeSample> ?end >> ex:Name ?attr4 } . 
FILTER(STR(?attr2) = "47.1234") 
}

Output: This query did not returned anything.
So, How to fetch relations with the filter on attribute type double which might be present on some of the relations?
Update: Fix syntax of last query.

Both SELECT queries look syntactically valid to me, except of the (proposed to fix) linebreaks in the last query. Therefore the exception of the first SELECT query might be a bug of the SPARQL endpoint. Beside of that, note that for both SELECT queries the expected result is empty, as no matching statement for ?start <edgeSample> ?end . is stated in the graph and 47.1237 != 47.1234 (probably a typo) for strings and double literals.

Hello, @JanMartinKeil, Yes 47.1237 != 47.1234, was typo, thanks for identifying ; Also we removed ?start <edgeSample> ?end ., but still query 1 returned same exception, where as case 2 query did not return any data.

I guess your WHERE clauses now start with OPTIONAL. Due to left-associativenes of the OPTIONAL keyword, this causes always empty results. Try to make the statement with predicate ex:Double not optional and move above the optional statement.
